# Floating right without changing the div order in html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, floating

I am trying to float:right divs without changing the order of the div list in html.
I have a list of divs with max of 4 shown in one line. When entering new line, all the remaining divs have to be floated right too.
Adjusting HTML div to display right is not an option, because div are loaded dynamically and can be set to hidden (different menus are shown to different roles, but the menu order has to stay).
Html is build on bootstrap.

Please se the example:
http://jsfiddle.net/mkLvs/3

(keep in mind, remaining divs in new line have to be floated on the right side.)

```
<style type="text/css">
.span3.menu {
text-align:center;
background-color:yellow;
padding:10px;
border: 1px solid black;
float:right;
}
.row-fluid.one {
float:right;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid one">
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu1</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu2</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu3</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu4</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu5</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu6</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu7</a></div>
    <div class="span3 menu"> <a href="#">Menu8</a></div>
</div> 
</div> 
</body>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using inline elements, without using `float`.

```
<div class='container'>
    <span><a href="#">Menu1</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu2</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu3</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu4</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu5</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu6</a></span>
    <span><a href="#">Menu7</a></span>
</div>

.container{
    text-align: right;
}

.container span{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 125px;
    height: 20px;
    margin: 3px 0px;
    background: yellow;
}
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9uXQD/3/)